# jQuery pjax is not working on Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pjax

I'm using expressjs framework and I want to enable jQuery pjax, everything is coded well, but it's not working in a pjax way yet!

I figured out that when I click on a link from `/login` to `/signup` for example: the logger give me this:

```
GET /signup?_pjax=%23content
GET /signup
```

It seems that the request is working multiple times!!!

This is the code that I'm using:

```
// main.js
$(document).pjax('a', '#content');
```

```
// app.js
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  res.render('account/login', {
    title: 'login page'
  });
});
app.get('/signup', function(req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    return res.redirect('/');
  }
  res.render('account/signup', {
    title: 'signup page'
  });
});
```

```
//layout.jade
body#content
  block content
```

```
//login.jade
extends ../layout
  block content
  ...etc
```

```
//signup.jade
extends ../layout
  block content
  ...etc
```

Can you help me, please?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out that i have to send a part of the layout jade, and everything will be nice, for more information see this [solution](https://gist.github.com/narirou/a186e62d5c3891e2ff44)